# How do I put a javascript variable inside the url?

Tags: javascript

So you know how sometimes websites have a little "?variable=value" thing at the end of their name? how do I use this? I'm pretty sure either A) the variable isn't getting deffined like it should or B) there is a problem regarding this portion of the code:

```
if (! variable) {
  var variable;
}
```

So how do I do this?

EDIT: Here is the full script I'm trying to run, it's purpose is for a simple password protected page, but I want to allow the password to be passed in the url so when switching pages you won't have to re-enter the password continuously.

```
  <script>
      var m = location.href.match(/[?&]variable=([^&]*)/),
      password;
      if (m) {
        password = m[1];
      }
      var pass1="password";
      var pass2="abcd";
      if (password!==pass1 || password!==pass2) {
        password=prompt('Please enter your password to view this page!',' ');
        if (password==pass1 || password==pass2) {
          alert('Password Correct!');
        } else {
          history.go(-1);
        }
      }
  </script>
```

This code just prompts me no matter what is in the url.

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values/901144#901144

Comment: Why are you using `if (! m) {`? It's `if (m) {`!

Comment: Oops! Okay, I changed it and now it just prompts me for the password.

Comment: @Jack any ideas? I'm stumped. Also, password is undefined and I think this is the problem.

Comment: Well, what does the location in the address bar look like? i.e. what's `location.href`?

Comment: It looks like the web address, exactly like it. Something along the lines of `http://www.website.com/page?password=abcd` or at least, that's what came up when I "alert(location.href);"

Comment: Well, I think I figured it out.. this `var m = location.href.match(/[?&]variable=([^&]*)/),` needed to be `var m = location.href.match(/[?&]password=([^&]*)/),` of course now I just gotta tweak the code a bit...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameters in the query string are not automatically passed to Javascript; they're usually meant for server-side scripts. To get one variable you could do this:

```
var m = location.href.match(/[?&]variable=([^&]*)/),
password;

if (m) {
    password = m[1];
}
```

Comment: @BBMAN225 That's not very helpful. What did you try, why didn't it work?

Comment: Sorry, I tried this:

          var password = location.href.match(/[?&]variable=([^&]*)/);
          if (! password) {
            var password;
          }

Comment: @BBMAN225 I'm not even sure what that code is supposed to do, but fwiw I've updated my answer.

Comment: Well, I put your updated code in but it still seems to mess up. I tried to put this in the if (m) sequence but it didn't alert: "alert(password);"

Comment: @BBMAN225 Perhaps at this point it's better to update your question with the code as you have it now.

Comment: Okay done, please note that it is probably terrible and basic because I've never tried much more then a little variable handling here and there. Of course, I've done tutorials.

Comment: @BBMAN225 y u never copy/paste my code properly?

Comment: Sorry :P I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass variable like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var scrt_var = 10; 
</script>
<a href="2.html" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?key='+scrt_var;return false;">Link</a>
```

or like this:

put id attribute on anchor element

```
 <a id="link2">
```

set href attribute on page load event:

```
var scrt_var = 10;
var strLink = "2.html&Key=" + scrt_var;
document.getElementById("link2").setAttribute("href",strLink);
```

Comment: My question was regarding the reading of the variable, but this will surely help!